# Column manipulation of two different files using command line tools

Tags: python, bash, awk

I am trying to write a script which extracts changed columns of two rather similar datasets stored as tabular data in two different files. Here an example:

Starting data of file1.txt:

```
COLUMN_1 COLUMN_2 COLUMN_3 
-------- -------- -------- 
Value_1  Value_2  Value_3
```

Changed data of file2.txt:

```
COLUMN_1 COLUMN_2 COLUMN_3 
-------- -------- -------- 
Value_1  newValue Value_3
```

Resulting data:

```
COLUMN_2
--------
newValue
```

Which tools would you suggest to use for this? I am thinking of awk or python?

**Update**: 
Made a small mistake, the result should show the `newValue`

Comment: Will the old value and new value always be on the same row (line)? Can you just do `diff f1.txt f2.txt`?

Comment: Yes, the two files will always have three rows. Column header, seperator and the value row. I need to preserve the header row, otherwise the value is meaningless. With a simple diff the header infomation will be lost,isnt it?

Comment: Furthemore is it very important that columns where the values are not changed will not be saved. In a real world example there will be likely 100 columns and i only want to see the columns where a change was made.

Comment: Tab separated? Any spaces in the values or headers?

Comment: Currently seperated with whitespaces, no whitespaces in the header but in the values. I am tring to find a way using another delimiter than the whitespace. A solution where the data is seperated with comma, would also be sufficient for now.

Comment: Is your data fixed width? Then you so not need to change the delimiter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doodling in Python:

```
with open(fn1) as f1, open(fn2) as f2:
    head1, head2 = [next(fh).split() for fh in (f1, f2)]
    sep1, sep2 = [next(fh).split() for fh in (f1, f2)]
    v1, v2 = [next(fh).split() for fh in (f1, f2)]
    for i, (fi1, fi2) in enumerate(zip(v1, v2)):
        if fi1!=fi2:
            print('{}\n{}\n{}'.format(head2[i], sep2[i], fi2))
```

Prints:

```
COLUMN_2
--------
newValue
```

But that breaks down (as does an `awk` solution) if you ambiguously have whitespace in your values and as delimiters.

If you use a different delimiter, change `.split('character_that_is_delimiter')` in this file (or, better still, use the csv module...)

Comment: Wow, great. Now i only need a way to set an other delimiter on the data than the whitespace and this should work. I voted for this but my score is too low, so the vote does not show up.

Comment: You can still [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it is useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ paste file1 file2 | 
  awk 'NR==1 {split($0,h1)} 
       NR==2 {split($0,h2)} 
             {m=NF/2; 
              for(i=1;i<=m;i++) if($i!=$(i+m)) d[i]=$i;
              for(i=1;i<=m;i++) if(i in d) print h1[i]; 
              for(i=1;i<=m;i++) if(i in d) print h2[i]; 
              for(i=1;i<=m;i++) if(i in d) print d[i]}'

COLUMN_2
--------
Value_2
```